# Python Dictionary key within a key

Tags: python, dictionary

I don't know how to write this correctly.

```
Candy = {"sweetness": 1}
jonny = {"holding": Candy}
print(jonny["holding"["sweetness"]])
```

Basically I want the sweetness of whatever jonny is holding. Also, what jonny is holding will change throughout the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just.

```
print(jonny["holding"]["sweetness"])
>> 1
```

`jonny["holding"]` gives to you `Candy` dict. So, then get `sweetness` key from it.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out the correct way is:

```
jonny["holding"]["sweetness"]
```

The reason why is that `jonny["holding"]` returns the value of `holding` in the `jonny` dict. The value of `jonny["holding"]` in this case is the `Candy` dictionary.

```
jonny["holding"] == Candy
```

Therefore, if you can do `Candy["sweetness"]` then by simple substitution, you can then do `jonny["holding"]["sweetness"]`

You can nest dictionaries or lists to any level using this concept by following that pattern, eg:

```
jonny["holding"]["sweetness"]["otherkey"][0]["another_key"]["etc"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do as follows:

```
print(jonny["holding"]["sweetness"])
```